# :after element is on lower layer than a parent

Tags: css, z-index, pseudo-element

I have a code like this:

```
> .arrow {
  cursor: pointer;
  user-select: none;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin-left: 1em;
  transition: background-color .1s ease;
  z-index: 1;
  &:hover {
    background-color: ${backgroundColors.green3};
    &:after {
      background: url(${arrowPointToRightSvg});
      z-index: 2;
      position: relative;
    }
  }
}
& > .arrow:after {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  content: ' ';
  height: 13px;
  width: 7px;
  background: url(${arrowPointToRightGreenSvg});
  background-size: cover;
}
```

The expected result is that :after element would be shown above its parent, but background of .arrow (while hovered) overlaps the content (an svg with arrow) of :after element. Why is this happening and what can i do to make my background of :after element to be shown with higher priority?

Comment: How I solved the problem:
At the moment I've been changing my :after element background I needed to add some properties again (content, height, width, background-size).

Comment: can't you make it work with position relative (to arrow class ) and position absolute (to :after)?